# HTML signature in Windows 10 Mail app possible?

Tags: email, windows-10

Is there a way to use a HTML signature in the standard Microsoft Windows delivered Mail app?

Comment: So far it is not possible :/

Comment: I couldn't find any way to do that ,but you have other ways for reaching your goal. 1-you can easily use another app,2-you can copy and past html from browser to the end of email (it will work as real html) ,3- you can make a program or web to do so (getting email ---adding signature-->send it to you or whom you want ,4-add a clickable link and you can design a html page using java script or linking to an html page. please tell me if any of abow is good

Answer (score 8):

I work on the Mail app for Microsoft, and while this is not possible yet we are tracking this as top feedback as we work on improvements to the app.

Comment: Where is this tracked? Is it on UserVoice? Can we vote on it?

Comment: As the default signature seems to have a html element; `Mail`, there must be an unofficial workaround. Are you willing to share it?

Comment: Nearly a year later, is there anything new to share?

Comment: I consider this a really important feature that is missing from the otherwise *perfect* mail app. So impressed by Win10 Mail, this would make it a killer app.

Comment: More than three years later, and still nothing but crickets… so much for “tracking this as top feedback”. :-/